# build files in the command line

Tags: java, command-line, corba

Hi I have a quick question about java and the command line terminal 
I am doing a corba chatroom and I want to download a sample application on found on GitHub https://github.com/bobbyrne01/chatsystem-corba

There is a readme file that goes as follows 
Build

Open a terminal on server machine:

```
cd git/chatsystem-corba/
idlj -fall -td classes/ ChatSystem.idl
orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost &
java -classpath classes/ Server -ORBInitialPort 1050
```

My problem is when I get to line 4 java -classpath classes/ Server -ORBInitialPort 1050
I dont know what to type into the command line ..
Here a snapshot of my files [image]

There is probably a simple solution but can't figure it out
    Please note my environment for my jdk is set up ....

Comment: Why not just that? `java -classpath classes/ Server -ORBInitialPort 1050` should start the server on port 1050.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..this is the reponse form the command line                                       Error: Could not find or load main class Server

Comment: Look in the `classes` folder. Is there a `Server.class` file? If not, you built it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on server ..

```
javac *.java classes/*.java classes/ChatServerPackage/*.java
idlj -fall -td classes/ ChatSystem.idl
orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost &
java -classpath .:classes/ Server -ORBInitialPort 1050
```

And on client ..

```
java -classpath .:classes/ Client -ORBInitialPort 1050
```